# openoffice: # of Fridays between epoch and date X?

Tags: date, openoffice.org

I'm working on a family budget in OpenOffice, and I would like to count the # of Fridays since an epoch (so that I count the # of pay periods).

Is there a function that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

ooh, here we go; I just need to do

```
=FLOOR((X-X0)/7;1)
```

where X is a reference to the desired Date cell, and X0 is an constant Date equivalent that falls on a Friday, since OpenOffice appears to convert dates to floating-point numbers with a scaling factor of 1.0 = 1 day.